# How do you access properties of base class in Typescript?

Tags: inheritance, properties, typescript, superclass

There was a suggestion of using code like this

```
class A {
    // Setting this to private will cause class B to have a compile error
    public x: string = 'a';
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(){super();}
    method():string {
        return super.x;
    }
}

var b:B = new B();
alert(b.method());
```

and it even got 9 votes. But when  you paste it on the official TS playground 
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/
it gives you and error.

How to access the x property of A from B?

Answer (score 50):

use `this` rather than `super` :

```
class A {
    // Setting this to private will cause class B to have a compile error
    public x: string = 'a';
}

class B extends A {
    // constructor(){super();}
    method():string {
        return this.x;
    }
}

var b:B = new B();
alert(b.method());
```

Comment: Champion! Sorry, don't have enough reputation to +1